# DB query failed in php

Tags: php, mysql

the php code does not return any results from the database

```
 $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pelicula";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($result_array, $row);
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($result_array);
    $conn->close();
```

Comment: Is there any error? Does the table have rows of data?

Comment: yes, my cuestion is why?
and the table have rows

Comment: Why don't use just use `$result->fetch_all()` if you want the full resultset?

Comment: i tried it and i get an empty array, but the num_rows returns 2 as the rows in the table

Answer (score 0):

```
 $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pelicula";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $result_array=[];
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($result_array, $row);
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($result_array);
    $conn->close();`enter code here`
```

The $result_array had to be created and instantiate before using it with the array_push function!!!